# Entity Framework confusions

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, binding

This is WPF + MVVM + EF. I have a table of Sales Orders in my DB. In the UI, I show a ComboBox with all SalesOrderNumbers and a Grid with Labels and TextBoxes that shows the details of selected order in the ComboBox. Consider the following ViewModel:

```
Class SalesOrderViewModel
    Public Property AllSalesOrderNumbers As List(Of Integer)

    Public Sub New()
        AllSalesOrderNumbers = context.SalesOrders.Select(Function(x) x.orderNumber).ToList()
        If AllSalesOrderNumbers.Count > 0 Then SelectedOrderNumber = AllSalesOrderNumbers(0)
    End Sub

    Private Property mSelectedOrderNumber As Integer
    Public Property SelectedOrderNumber As Nullable(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return mSelectedOrderNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Integer))
            mSelectedOrderNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedOrder As SalesOrder
        Get
           Return context.SalesOrders.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.orderNumber = SelectedOrderNumber)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

In the UI, ComboBox's `ItemsSource` is bound to `AllSalesOrderNumbers` and `SelectedValue` is bound to `SelectedOrderNumber` (with `Mode=OneWayToSource`). On the other hand, the Grid's DataContext is bound to `SelectedOrder`. Whole of it is working fine.

My question is about the New Sales Order button. For adding new record, have added an `ICommand` to my ViewModel that basically does the following:

```
Dim NewOrder = context.SalesOrders.CreateObject()
context.SalesOrders.AddObject(NewOrder)
mSelectedOrderNumber = NewOrder.orderNumber
AllSalesOrderNumbers.Add(mSelectedOrderNumber)
```

I'm confused about the following:

1. `SelectedOrder` queries the model for the current value of SelectedOrderNumber property. Since the DB doesn't yet have this new record, it returns null. How do I ask it to look into local context object before going to the DB?
2. Unlike DataSets, it doesn't assign a negatively incrementing identity value to `orderNumber`, so I'm wondering what will happen if I add another order.
3. I do not see the newly added order object in `context.SalesOrders` collection after the 2nd line above (`context.SalesOrders.AddObject(NewOrder)`) executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical answers:

> 1.SelectedOrder queries the model for the current value of SelectedOrderNumber property. Since the DB doesn't yet have this new record, it returns null. How do I ask it to look into local context object before going to the DB?

You can query the local collection of a `DbSet` like so:

```
context.SalesOrders.Local.FirstOrDefault(...)
```

> 2.Unlike DataSets, it doesn't assign a negatively incrementing identity value to orderNumber, so I'm wondering what will happen if I add another order.

When you add new `Order`s, EF will keep track of each of them as a separate instances.

> 3.I do not see the newly added order object in context.SalesOrders collection after the 2nd line above (context.SalesOrders.AddObject(NewOrder)) executes.

See 1. It's in the `Local` collection.

Architectural answer: having a `context` in your view model is not the best choice. A view model should not worry about its data, it should receive data and after that be self contained. Its responsibility is to respond to user interaction and notify these to the controller or service layer. So the model should be populated with a list of `Order`s, after which the context is disposed. When new orders are added the model should tell the controller, either instantly or after a save command, and maybe receive a command to (re)display the `Order`. As such the view model is relieved from knowing the technical details of a data layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is that my SalesOrder table has a whole lot of columns and can have thousands of rows. I don't want to make my app a memory hog by loading the entire table into the VM. So what I'm doing is to just load the Order Numbers initially and then query for the actual row as and when required. BTW, I'm a newbie in WPF + MVVM world (from Button1_Click kind of WinForms coding) and already going thru a steep learning curve, so adding yet another layer may become unmanagable for me at this point.

Comment: OK, I understand. Well, the `Local` collection should do. Still, I'm convinced that some time investment now in a better separated architecture will save time later. You can let the view model issue a command to the controller to query `Order`s specified by Id.

Comment: I don't see a 'Local' member in my SalesOrder properties. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's part of the DbContext API (DbSet), apparently you use ObjectContext?